# JQUERY check if listbox option is selected, used as condition in an if loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have 2 checkbox categories, one dropdown list, and a submit button in a form. The button shall stay 'disabled' until one checkbox of category A is checked and one of category B options is checked and an option of the select list is selected.
It works for the checkboxes (when I tested without list) but there is an issue with the list.
When I fill out the form from top to bottom (func --> plat --> lang) it doesn't work. Somehow it works when I select "lang" first and then check the boxes. It also works from top to bottom when I check another checkbox after the language was selected. That's weird.
So here is the HTML:

```
<h3>choose func</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="func1" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="func1" value="1" id="func1" /> func1 <br/>
<input type="hidden" name="func2" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="func2" value="1" id="func2" /> func2<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="func3" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="func3" value="1" id="func3"/> func3<br/>
<br/>
<h3>choose plat</h3>
<input type="hidden" name="plat1" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="plat1" value="1" id="plat1" /> plat1<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="plat2" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="plat2" value="1" id="plat2" /> plat2<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="plat3" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="plat3" value="1" id="plat3" /> plat3<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="plat4" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="plat4" value="1" id="plat4" /> plat4<br/>
<br/>
<h3>choose lang</h3>
<select name="sprache">
<option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
<option name="deutsch" id="deutsch">Deutsch</option>
<option name="englisch" id="englisch">Englisch</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<script>
</script>
<input type="submit" name="abfrage" class="inputButton" id="idAbfragen" value="Abfragen" disabled="">
```

And the jQuery/js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#func1, #func2, #func3, #plat1, #plat2, #plat3, #plat4, #deutsch, #englisch").change(function () {
        if (($("#func1").is(':checked') || $("#func2").is(':checked') || $("#func3").is(':checked')) 
        && 
        ($("#plat1").is(':checked') || $("#plat2").is(':checked') || $("#plat3").is(':checked') || $("#plat4").is(':checked')) 
        && 
        ($("#deutsch").is(':selected') || $("#englisch").is(':selected')))          
        {   
            $('.inputButton').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else 
        {
            $('.inputButton').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. You can reproduce this issue in the fiddle i set up: https://jsfiddle.net/3zqf4fxv/

I hope there is a fix.
Thanks and Regards!

Comment: Change `$("#func1, #func2, #func3, #plat1, #plat2, #plat3, #plat4, #deutsch, #englisch")` to `$(":input")`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3zqf4fxv/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine and also saves some typing

Comment: Would you like a more scalable solution so you're not passing each individual DOM element into your conditionals? IE - If you had a list of 100 items for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$("#func1, #func2, #func3, #plat1, #plat2, #plat3, #plat4, #deutsch, #englisch")
```

to

```
$(":input")
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3zqf4fxv/1)**

The issue lies with using `#deutsch, #englisch` in your selectors. The select element changes, not the options. The `:input` is just a jQuery shortcut to select what you have already in your example, but note if you have other input elements on your page this would not be ideal. You can just replace `#deutsch, #englisch` with `select[name='sprache']`.

Ex:

```
$("#func1, #func2, #func3, #plat1, #plat2, #plat3, #plat4, select[name='sprache']")
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wtLju2ya/)**